# Difference between interpolate() and fillna() in pandas

Tags: python, bigdata, pandas, jupyter

Since interpolate and fillna method does the same work of filling na values. What is the basic difference between the two. What is the significance of having these two different methods?? Can anyone explain me in layman terms. I already visited through the official documentation and wanted to know the difference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`fillna` fills the `NaN` values with a given number with which you want to substitute. It gives you an option to fill according to the index of rows of a `pd.DataFrame` or on the name of the columns in the form of a python `dict`.

But `interpolate` is a god in filling. It gives you the flexibility to fill the missing values with many kinds of interpolations between the values like linear (which `fillna` does not provide) in the example provided below and many more interpolations possible. For example

```
>> import pandas as pd, numpy as np
>> df = pd.Series([1, np.nan, np.nan, 3])
>> df.interpolate()
0    1.000000
1    1.666667
2    2.333333
3    3.000000
dtype: float64
```

Pandas documentation on [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [interpolate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) is very clear on this.

Comment: Understood. Suppose if i want to fill only some specific values(may be in range or without range) that can also be done using interpolation. Right ?

Comment: Is it filling in with specific values or filling specific values as in cells of a DataFrame?

Comment: filling specific values in cell at some particular locations only but at a time many values should be filled or in some range